# Qnx message prefix

Tags: c, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I can not implement messaging between processes in QNX with the mechanism of the perfixes. I have tried many ways but all in vain.

```
       #define PREFIX_POSITION "stat_pos"

        char receiveBuffer = 0;
        char replyBuffer[25];
        name_attach_t *positionPrefix;
        dispatch_t *dpp;
        int rcvid;

        dpp = dispatch_create();

        if (positionPrefix = name_attach(NULL, PREFIX_POSITION, 0) == NULL){
            printf("prefix - null\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        positionPrefix = name_attach(dpp, PREFIX_POSITION, 0);

        while(true){
            rcvid = MsgReceive(positionPrefix->chid, &receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), NULL);
            switch(receiveBuffer){
                case 'Q':
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    //Do something
                    break;
            }
            MsgReply(rcvid, REPLY_INDEX, &replyBuffer, sizeof(replyBuffer));
            receiveBuffer = 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

`name_attach ()` function always returns null. What could be the problem?

Comment: And is the `errno` value after `name_attach()` returned `NULL`?

Comment: @purplepsycho, what do you mean?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fn%2Fname_attach.html), when `name_attach` fails, it set the variable `errno` to understand the error cause. Instead of `printf("prefix - null\n");`, just write `printf("name_attach(): %d\n", errno);`, or `perror("name_attach");`

Comment: @UjinUkr Is your problem solved? If not, can you share the errno as suggested by @purplepsycho?